# How to add more methods in AsyncTask class?

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I want to build some connection between my android and the server (in my PC) via Java sockets. Simply, it just send data such as string and integer over the local network.

I read about the AsyncTask class. I added my socket connection code in the `doInBackground()` method in the class (the class named `RemoteClient`). Here is the code to connect and initialize the connection via socket:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        Log.i("Socket","Connecting to the remote server: " + host);
        try{
            socket = new Socket(host,8025);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Simply i just want to make a method `sendInteger(int value)` to the server via the socket. I already finished the connection, it connects well.

So, where should I put the `sendInteger(int value)` method, can I just put the method in the `RemoteClient` class along with the implemented methods?

I want to call the `sendInteger(int value)` methods when a button is clicked.

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can just put the sendInteger inside of your AsyncTask. I like to use the Constructor instead of the AsyncTask Parameters, because it is more flexibel. You can implement an interface as a callback to receive the server answer inside your UI. onPostExecute will always called by the system just after onBackground was executed. onPostExecute runs also on the UI Thread so you don't have to deal with coming back to your UI Thread since your AsyncTask will run on a different thread.

Your code would look like this:

```
Fragmentclass or Activity:

private void onButtonClick() {
  ...
  RemoteClient rc = new RemoteClient(value, (response) -> {
     Log.d(response);
  };
  rc.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
  ...
}

public class RemoteClient extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  private Callback callback;
  private int intValue;

  public RemoteClient(int intValue, Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    this.intValue = intValue;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
      Log.i("Socket","Connecting to the remote server: " + host);
      try{
        socket = new Socket(host,8025);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        sendInteger(intvalue);
      } catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;

  }

  private void sendInteger(int value) {
    // send the integer
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) { 
    if (callback != null) {
       callback.response;
    }
  }

private interface Callback {
  void serverResponse(String value);
}
}
```

If you want to be more fliexble you can implement a NetworkManager class which just starts your Async Task. Then you can always pass a String as JSON to your AsyncTask. Or you just use AsyncTask but then i would recommend to use inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can I call the function directly like `rc.sendInteger(value)` in the main class? Because i was calling the `rc.execute()` inside onCreate method to initialize the connection, so it connects automatically to the server on start. Thanks

Comment: No this is unhandy, because after doInBackground is executed, the Task will be killed and garabage collected. Consider what I also mentioned. Use a NetworkManager as a Singleton, build up your connection there and Parse your Input to JSON with GSON, then you don't have to deal with different inputs. You could also use Retrofit!  It is an easy to use and from google recommended lib for network communication.